# Compare two string and ignore (but not replace) accents. PHP

Tags: php, string, non-ascii-characters

I got (for example) two strings:

```
$a = "joao";
$b = "joão";

if ( strtoupper($a) == strtoupper($b)) {
    echo $b;
}
```

I want it to be true even tho the accentuation. However I need it to ignore the accentuation instead of replacing because I need it to echo "joão" and not "joao".

All answers I've seen replace "ã" for "a" instead of making the comparison true. I've been reading about normalizing it, but I can't make it work either. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You could use the replacement functions just for the comparison but still output the original string

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php

Comment: @MrBr1ghtSide note he says he doesn't want to replace the characters, only compare them

Comment: Well if he can replace them, he can compare the strings since they will be the same

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Just convert the accents to their non-accented counter part and then compare strings. The function in my answer will remove the accents for you.

```
function removeAccents($string) {
    return strtolower(trim(preg_replace('~[^0-9a-z]+~i', '-', preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))), ' '));
}

$a = "joaoaaeeA";
$b = "joãoâàéèÀ";

var_dump(removeAccents($a) === removeAccents($b));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/1097282)

Comment: demo link broken,  does  it work for all accents characters ? like â à  é è  ?

Comment: Also Capital letters with accents ?

Comment: Updated the answer to use more sample characters

Comment: But why the strtolower()?

Comment: Upvoted, great answer!  But, unfortunately, this solution fails on the following case: `Ōsugi Sakae`. =\

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Thank you. I tested the string you provided and it seemed to work for me: https://3v4l.org/o5T4B

Comment: Oh, whoa, that is interesting!  Your linked code works! (yey!)  Good --> `return preg_replace('/[\x{0300}-\x{036f}]/u',"",normalizer_normalize($str,Normalizer::FORM_D));`  But this is diff from your answer, which, when I test, returns "-sugi".  Take a look: https://ideone.com/CE7qcl

Comment: Weird. The code is identical but gives different results. Works locally for me, too, so I am guessing that site has some kind of configuration that is different than what the other site and I have.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to share an elegant solution that avoids the usage of htmlentities and that doesn't need to manually list all chars replacements. It is the traduction in php of the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript) post.

```
function removeAccents($str) {
    return preg_replace('/[\x{0300}-\x{036f}]/u',"",normalizer_normalize($str,Normalizer::FORM_D));
}

$a = "joaoaaeeA";
$b = "joãoâàéèÀ";

var_dump(removeAccents($a) === removeAccents($b));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

Answer (score -2):

It's not a plain PHP solution but works very well for this situation, run this query on MySQL:

```
SELECT 'joão' = 'joao'
```

So if you have access to mysql you can use it from PHP.

Comment: And FYI: this is true only depending on the collation of the table, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813620/how-to-remove-accents-in-mysql/17045193