# PHP str_ireplace same word with accent or not

Tags: php, str-replace

Hope this is a better...

I set "mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");" before doing a standard query SELECT-FROM-WHERE. This query performs an accent insentive compare.

str_ireplace(search, replace, text) search does an accent sensitive compare. I would need search to do an accents insentive compare.

I want to highlight the word "Français". I replace "Français" by

```
<mark>Français</mark>
```

but at the same time I want to replace "Francais" by

```
<mark>Francais</mark>
```

---

older post:

I use a simple way to highlight some text:

```
$markReplace = "<mark>" . $wordToSearch . "</mark>";
$fullText = str_ireplace($wordToSearch, $markReplace, $fullText);
echo $fullText;
```

It works fine, the problem is that sometimes the same $wordToSearch can have a accent or not. For example "huître-huitre", "Francais-Français", "echo-écho" because of typo errors. And contrary to MySql, str_ireplace doesn't detect a letter with an accent as the same letter without the accent.

```
$unwanted_array = array('Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
                        'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U',
                        'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss', 'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c',
                        'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o',
                        'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y' );
$str = strtr( $str, $unwanted_array );
```

A solution that would use something like this doesn't work because it will change all the accents in $fullText. I need to keep the original words when I echo $fullText.

Can't figure out the solution.

Thanks... Andy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two string and ignore (but not replace) accents. PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27680624/compare-two-string-and-ignore-but-not-replace-accents-php)

Comment: What does the replacement version have? You'll have the issue with uppercase vs. lowercase as well, right?

Comment: all those string functions are ASCII-only since v8.2. Use mb_* analogues.

Comment: @Constantin OP needs to know if `ê` or `ë` is being replaced and then adjust replacement based on that.

Comment: @Blackhole The question is the proper one, but I don't see a clear answer in the link.

Comment: @user3783243 I'm using str_ireplace, so the capitalisation is not an issue.

Comment: So you're looking for case _and_ accent insensitive search and replace?

Comment: @Andy62 `str_ireplace` matches `A` and `a` though, you then would replace one version with the alternative. e.g. https://3v4l.org/OhCmt https://3v4l.org/NvlWg. It's the same issue as accents, or I'd think as you're changing the characters.

Comment: i give to another post the solution.. activate mbstring then <?php $str='àÀíÍÃ Dàlidà ÍOÃNA ';echo 'old str: '.$str.' '.mb_detect_encoding($str).'<hr>';$str=mb_ereg_replace('À', 'A', $str);$str=mb_ereg_replace('Ã', 'A', $str);$str=mb_ereg_replace('Í', 'I', $str);$str=mb_ereg_replace('à', 'a', $str);$str=mb_ereg_replace('í', 'i', $str);echo 'new str:'.$str; ?>

Answer (score 2):

Okay so first of all, converting one set of characters [eg: accented] to an equivalent form [eg: unaccented] according to some rules is called "transliteration".

The intl extension provides a handy transliterator class that we can invoke with simply:

```php
$translit = Transliterator::create('Latin-ASCII;');
$foo = $translit->transliterate('Français'); // Francais
```

So painstakingly maintaining a list of "unwanted" characters and their replacements is not necessary.

Secondly, accented characters are not always single codepoints, `ç` may be represented by either the unified codepoint, or a two-codepoint sequence consisting of a plain `c` and a combining mark representing the accent.

The unit comprising a single visual glyph is referred to as a Grapheme.

Thirdly, the your requirements [case-insensitve *and* accent-insensitive] essentially requires that we have to build our own custom string matching procedure.

First, we need a GraphemeIterator to traverse the UTF8 string properly. intl's `IntlBreakIterator::createCharacterInstance()` does the heavy lifting, but returns byte offsets, so lets wrap that in another iterator that actually pops out graphemes:

```php
class GraphemeIterator implements \Iterator {
    protected $i, $string, $offset;
    
    public function __construct($string) {
        $this->string = $string;
        
        $i = IntlBreakIterator::createCharacterInstance();
        $i->setText($string);
        $this->i = $i->getIterator();
        
        $this->init();
    }
    
    protected function init() {
        $this->offset = $this->i->current();
        $this->i->next();
    }
    
    public function length() {
        return grapheme_strlen($this->string);
    }
    
    public function tell() {
        return [ $this->offset, $this->i->current()];
    }
    
    // Iterator Interface functions
    public function current(): mixed {
        return substr($this->string, $this->offset, $this->i->current() - $this->offset);
    }
    
    public function key(): mixed {
        return $this->i->key();
    }
    
    public function next(): void {
        $this->offset = $this->i->current();
        $this->i->next();
    }
    
    public function rewind(): void {
        $this->i->rewind();
        $this->init();
    }
    
    public function valid(): bool {
        return $this->i->valid();
    }
}
```

Now we need something that can compare two strings after applying some arbitrary comparisons:

```php
class TransformingComparator {
    protected $transforms = [];
    
    public function __construct(array $transforms) {
        foreach($transforms as $transform) {
            $this->addTransform($transform);
        }
    }
    
    protected function addTransform(callable $transform) {
        $this->transforms[] = $transform;
    }
    
    protected function transform($input) {
        $output = $input;
        foreach($this->transforms as $transform) {
            $output = $transform($output);
        }
        return $output;
    }
    
    public function compare($a, $b) {
        return $this->transform($a) <=> $this->transform($b);
    }
}
```

and a function that can use those to locate the occurrences of the search string:

```php
function findAllInGraphemeString($needle, $haystack, $comparator) {
    $t_it = new GraphemeIterator($haystack);
    $s_it = new GraphemeIterator($needle);
    
    $s = 0;
    $sl = $s_it->length();
    
    $out = [];
    $cur = [];
    
    for( $t=0, $tl=$t_it->length(); $t<$tl; ++$t ) {
        if( $comparator($t_it->current(), $s_it->current()) === 0 ) {
            if( empty($cur) ) {
                $cur[] = $t_it->tell()[0];
            }
            if( ++$s >= $sl ) {
                $cur[] = $t_it->tell()[1];
                $out[] = $cur;
                $cur = [];
                $s = 0;
                $s_it->rewind();
            } else {
                $s_it->next();
            }
            $t_it->next();
        } else {
            // on aborted partial match restart from current
            if( count($cur) != 0 ) {
                $s = 0;
                $cur=[];
                --$t;
            } else {
                $t_it->next();
            }
            $s_it->rewind();
        }
    }
    
    return $out;
}
```

and finally a function that can perform the actual transformation:

```php
function transformSubstrings(string $text, array $boundaries, callable $transform) {
    $output = '';
    $offset = 0;
    
    foreach($boundaries as $bound) {
        $output .= substr($text, $offset, $bound[0]-$offset);
        $output .= $transform(substr($text, $bound[0], $bound[1]-$bound[0]));
        $offset = $bound[1];
    }
    return $output . substr($text, $bound[1]);
}
```

We can finally put this together as::

```php
$translit = Transliterator::create('Latin-ASCII;');
$transforms = [
    [$translit, 'transliterate'], // remove accents
    'mb_strtolower'
];
$tc = new TransformingComparator($transforms);

$text = 'lorem ipsum frFrançais dolor sit français amet adsplicing dit';
$search = 'Francais';

echo transformSubstrings(
    $text,
    findAllInGraphemeString($search, $text, [$tc, 'compare']),
    function($a){
        return sprintf('<mark>%s</mark>', $a);
    }
);
```

Output:

```
lorem ipsum <mark>Français</mark> dolor sit <mark>français</mark> amet adsplicing dit <mark>francais</mark>
```

and yes, I got [nerd sniped](https://xkcd.com/356/) *hard* on this one.

---

Edit: Now that you've mentioned collations it occurs to me that intl has a `Collator` class, and it looks like `TransformingComparator` is now longer relevant and can be substituted out like:

```php
$col = new Collator('fr-ca'); // or whatever locale you're using
$col->setStrength(Collator::PRIMARY);
// ...
transformSubstrings(
    $text,
    findAllInGraphemeString($search, $text, [$col, 'compare']),
    function($a){
        return sprintf('<mark>%s</mark>', $a);
    }
)
```

Which will likely also be a fair bit faster, since it's likely using a lookup instead of running all the transforms.

Comment: Is that similar to what MySql does with a query, accent independent? It uses the collation on a table to determine how texts should be compared?

Comment: More or less. I'm not familiar with the particular implementation of collations, but I would wager that they use pre-computed values and a lookup rather than converting on the fly.

Comment: Updated the answer swapping intl's `Collator` in place of the `TransformingComparator`.

Comment: I'm a bit lost, which programs (6) shown above should I use? Thanks.